# GCM HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() -Notification not sent-

Tags: android, jakarta-ee, tomcat, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I successfully run my app and registered a device on my server so i get "*1 device(s) registered*" and "*send message*" button. But when I click on the "*send message*" button i get the following error:

I am using tomcat and the Android Example Project as told here:
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/server.html

```
    HTTP Status 500 - Servlet.init() for servlet SendAllMessagesServlet threw exception

    type Exception report

    message Servlet.init() for servlet SendAllMessagesServlet threw exception

    description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

    exception

    javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet SendAllMessagesServlet threw exception
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    root cause

    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument cannot be null
        com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.nonNull(Sender.java:553)
        com.google.android.gcm.server.Sender.<init>(Sender.java:88)
        com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.newSender(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:62)
        com.google.android.gcm.demo.server.SendAllMessagesServlet.init(SendAllMessagesServlet.java:53)
        org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
        org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
        org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
        org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
        org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
        org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(AprEndpoint.java:1852)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the Apache Tomcat/7.0.41 logs.
```

Please can someone help Please

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the API Key .
So I get a new api key and switch the old one with the new one and it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The json-simple-1.1.jar should copy into the WEB-INF/lib folder of your web application. this is the solution :)